# Chart Control Inside SSRS ReportViewer is Viewable From Localhost But Not Internet

Tags: .net, asp.net, reporting-services, charts

A project I own was just moved from an older server to a new one, and in the process of moving the web folder, re-deploying the SSRS reports, restoring the database, configuring IIS, etc... I have lost the ability to view the [Microsoft Chart Controls](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=130f7986-bf49-4fe5-9ca8-910ae6ea442c&DisplayLang=en) that are embedded in the SSRS reports, that are then displayed by a Microsoft.ReportViewer.

I could view them both locally and remotely (via the internet) on the old server. I can view them if I preview the SSRS report in Visual Studio. The report displays fine, only missing all the embedded charts. I can still view them locally through the web browser, just not from the internet.

What am I missing?

I tried giving permissions to the ChartImageHandler temp storage folder, but it didn't work.

I'm getting the Javascript error: Error: ClientReport380ec8ca0c294a809e9986c1bef9db1c is undefined

Answer (score 0):

I noticed when I added MS Charts to my project that you had to install them, rather than just place a dll in your bin folder.  Is it possible the new server has not had the charts EXE file installed?

Comment: MS Charts are installed on this server.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at google chart api. All you would need is an image control with the url pointing to google charts. It's fantastic & as long as you dont have .5 million requests, google is happy to serve you.

Answer (score 0):

They key to this puzzle is the change in servers: we went from IIS to IIS7. IIS7 requires the line  in the web.config handlers section.